# Elegant pattern for scoped_lock to access resource?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, boost

I have objects in containers that are access-controlled with mutexes.  I often do something like:

```
rsrc *r;
{
    scoped_lock l(mtx);
    r = container.pop( );
}
// ... use r
```

(I use scoped_lock to ensure clean up after exceptions, etc.)  However, I don't like the { ... } block that's not part of an explicit control structure (it's only there to make a scope for the scoped_lock) and I don't like the null initialization of *r* followed by (probable but not certain) assignment in the { ... } block.

I can do something like this:

```
inline rsrc *locked_pop( mutex &mtx, container &c ) { scoped_lock l(mtx); return c.pop( ); }
```

and then

```
rsrc *r = locked_pop( mtx, container );
```

which is OK, but I have situations where I need to get several items from same (or different) container, under the same lock.

Do you know of an elegant, general way of doing this?  (This is not specifically a Boost question, but I'm using those libraries so a Boost-ism would be fine.)

Comment: I would probably return a `struct`.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::tuple<resource_a, resource_b> lock_and_pop(std::mutex& m, container& c)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    auto& top = container.front();
    auto result = std::make_tuple(std::move(top.res_a), std::move(top.res_b));
    container.pop_front();
    return result;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for std::tuple, which I didn't know.  (The "return a struct" idea is fine, but having to code structs for each set of things you might want to return is tedious.)  Between tuple<> and scoped_lock::unlock(), I'm all set!

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambdas.

```
template<class F>
decltype(auto) while_locked(mutex& m,F&&f){
  auto lock = scoped_lock(m);
  return std::forward<F>(f);
}
```

Used like:

```
auto* r = while_locked(mtx, [&]{return container.pop( );});
```

Now, I like binding my locks to my locked data.  So I wrote `thread_safe<T>` which exposes `read(F&&)const` and `write(F&&)const` and `-> const`.

Their signatures are of type `[T]->(T->U)->U`, where `[T]` is a wrapped `T`, `(T->U)` is the `F` passed in, and `U` is what `F` returns.

Read aquires a read lock, write a write lock, and `->` returns a read-lock holding object with an overloaded `->` operator returning `T const*`.

We can also handle multiple access with an orsering on the mutexes.

Then we get:

```
auto* r = container.write([](auto&&container){return container.pop_back();});
```

which is sort of slick.

The `->` trick relies on the fact that `a->b` is defined as `(a.operator->())->b` for non-pointer-types.  So we can return a lock-holding temporary that then has an `operator->` which returns the pointer.

This lets us do `bool b = container->empty()`, and it seamlessly does a read lock, reads the value of `empty`, stores it, and then unlocks the read lock.

Answer (score 0):

There is none. If you want to lock a resource and avoid locking it in each single instruction. The best is local access to the resource, as shown in your question.

Comment: Thanks.   Looking around, I see example code where people are calling .unlock() on a scoped_lock_var.  If that's valid (I'm still trying to tell for sure) then it makes my problem easier -- I want to use a scoped_lock to ensure cleanup, but I don't want an extra scope just to make the locked section shorter.  If I can unlock after I'm done fiddling, *and* the exit from the scope won't double-unlock (or do something else ugly) then that's my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize scoped_lock had an unlock() function that would allow unlocking prior to destruction of the scoped_lock (I thought ~scoped_lock() was the only way to unlock, and any other unlock() would result in a double-unlock when the scoped_locker went out of scope).  Since you can unlock() prior to the end of the scope, this is elegant enough for me:

```
void consume_resource( locked_container &c ) {
    scoped_lock l(c.mtx);
    rsrc *r1 = c.pop( );
    rsrc *r2 = c.pop( );
    l.unlock( );
    // CONTAINER NOT LOCKED ANY MORE, DON'T FIDDLE WITH IT (even to check empty(), etc.)
    // use resources pulled from container
}
```